# I already added activity but still getting the error "No launcher Activity Found"

Tags: android

i am new to android and i already have addes the activity but still getting the error "No Launcher activity found"

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity android:name=".startingPoint" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />
```

should be:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

It's case sensitive.

Also, your Activity should probably be named something better like `StartingActivity` to make it clear what type of class it is (and it shouldn't start with a lowercase letter).